# Current state of HDR output

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics, hdr

Most resources on the internet claim that after performing calculations in High Dynamic Range, where the values can be arbitrarily large (within type representation limits), the result must be transformed from HDR to Standard Dynamic Range, where the values are in range [0, 1] because this is the range representable by the display device.

Usually a tone-mapper is used, like an ACES style filmic tone-mapper, especially popular in PBR rendering. This is the case because the values would get clamped to the range [0, 1] anyway and anything above 1 would be ignored resulting in neither realistic or pleasing results... or would they?

I recently stumbled across the following NVIDIA article: https://developer.nvidia.com/rendering-game-hdr-display. It seems that by using NVIDIA and Windows specific APIs it is possible to output HDR values to take advantage of the capabilities of certain monitors to display a very large gamut of color and brightness.

I am wondering why isn't this really talked about. As far as I know even large game engines such as [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HDR.html) and [Unreal](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/ColorGrading/index.html) don't use this technique and instead use a tonemapper to output a SDR image.

Why is this the case? Is HDR output still in the phase of tech demos? Are there no consumer-grade displays capable of displaying it (despite many begin advertised as "HDR monitors")? Or did I  understand everything completely wrong and there is nothing such as HDR output and its all just an April Fools joke?

Edit: I would also appreciate some information about a cross platform approach to use HDR output, if possible, especially in OpenGL.

Comment: Yes there are ways to output HDR on windows and consoles. HDR monitors aren't very common yet and there doesn't seem to be a cross-platform approach to use HDR output in OpenGL (though [it seems to be worked on](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/9u3rei/what_stops_hdr_output_from_working_on_linux/)). Game engines may not implement it because it's not widely available.

Comment: @ybungalobill Thanks for your insight. I am still curious though why in my local store I find monitors advertised as being "HDR monitors". Is it just a marketing name that's not related to HDR output?

Comment: They may indeed support HDMI 2.0a or later, which means that they would display HDR given the correct setup.

Comment: You can find more information on the web saying that [Unreal has HDR support](https://forum.unity.com/threads/hdr-output.560182/). Also note that you'll still need to tone-map, because even with HDR your dynamic range isn't infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is HDR output still in the phase of tech demos?

What?? No, it is not. All Blu-rays and AAA games are HDR natively now, including good 10 bit textures in PQ transfer for games.

> are there non consumer-grade displays capable of displaying it

LG C9, CX, C1 are such displays, they are almost reference after calibration with internal 3DLUT.

> Or did I understand everything completely wrong and there is nothing such as HDR output and its all just an April Fools joke?

HDR will look different on different displays, that is mandated in the standard. That is what tonemapping technology **is**.

> approach to use HDR output, if possible, especially in OpenGL.

Best way to do it is Vulkan and DirectX. But even Linux now has all support. It is more like a driver thing. One needs drivers for this, it is the most complicated part.

Comment: `including good 10 bit textures in PQ transfer for games` Are you talking about textures like framebuffer attachments, or textures like albedo textures? If it's the latter, can you name any games that use 10 bit PQ (or BT2020 or P3 gamut) textures? I have yet to find an example of a game doing this.

Comment: Modern games have procedural generagion now. And they are in linear transfer usually, just converted for PQ by the driver. Many of them are WCG and HDR.

Comment: I don't think I am following. Can you name any games that are doing this?

Comment: Latest example, Forspoken uses P3 https://youtu.be/gYW5J52FxMw

Comment: Thank you for the example. Sadly having P3 values in the frame buffer does not mean that the textures were authored in P3. Every game I know of that uses wide color gamut actually achieves this using inverse tone mapping (Gears 5 for example), or simply by boosting the saturation (Doom Eternal). Most other games only use HDR luminance, and keep the color gamut in sRGB. The fact that the game only displays P3 colors when emissive effects (the fire) are on screen leads me to believe that at most, they authored the emissive effects in P3. Everything else is clearly in sRGB.

Comment: @Tara Another example, supports HGIG even on windows according to game dev I know: https://youtu.be/smot07UUOyw

Comment: Thank you. I still have to spend some more time looking into the call of duty HDR implementation. There is a technical presentation about it, which is probably more insightful than a YouTube video: https://research.activision.com/publications/archives/hdr-in-call-of-duty
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN1Uk6vJqRw
Btw, implementing HGiG doesn't require any specific technical feature. It's just a guideline on how to do things. You just need a HGiG-compatible PC monitor, which is rare.

Comment: @Tara Yes, Paul is that game dev. I know that presentation. But that is about older Call of duty. Anyway, HGIG is supported on OLED TV LG C9. It reports the display capabilities back to PC to support HGIG.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with which devices supports HGiG and which don't. HGiG does not presuppose feeding back display capabilities to the PC/Console. It presupposes linear PQ-tracking. The display's luminance capabilities can easily be determined using a calibration screen. On consoles the operating system has an HDR calibration screen and games are free to use that information or ignore it (many games ignore it). Either way, I am interested in games using wide color gamut TEXTURES, not HGiG. I never even brought up HGiG.